# Points in the Stone Cech compactification are intersection of open sets

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, ultrafilters, compactifications, stone-cech-compactification

Let $\beta \mathbb{N}$ be the Stone Cech compactification of the natural numbers and let $ x\in \beta \mathbb{N}$. Is it true that there exists a sequence of open sets $\{U_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\beta \mathbb{N}$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n = \{x\}$? What about if $ x$ is in the corona?

Comment: Any $G_\delta$ point of a compact Hausdorff space has a countable local base, and this certainly doesn't happen at any point of the remainder in $\beta\mathbb{N}$. In fact, any nonempty closed $G_\delta$ subset contained in the remainder has cardinality $\geq2^\mathfrak{c}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes if the point is from $\mathbb{N}$ (it is isolated).
No if the point is in $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ because in that subspace every nonempty $G_\delta$-set has nonempty interior, see [this paper](https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/%7Ehart/37/publications/the_papers/ency/d18-betaN-and-betaR.pdf) for more elementary properties of $\beta\mathbb{N}$.